# what's code to delete all list die

Tags: regex

i have result from checker
and I want to remove mass mailing die

example :
before i deleted :

```
Die | | example1@gmail.com | example1
Die | | example2@gmail.com | example2
Die | | example3@gmail.com | example3
Live | | example1@gmail.com | example1 | Order Date: May 1, 2015 | 5 Orders | 1 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-4374 ] | Alba Fitzpatrick | 26994 Brickville Rd | Sycamore, IL 60178 | (815) 508-0315
Live | | example2@gmail.com | example2 | Order Date: May 1, 2015 | Picked up | 24 Orders | 5 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-7814 ] | VISA [ XXXX-0370 ] | VISA [ XXXX-2441 ] | VISA [ XXXX-8129 ] | VISA [ XXXX-9986 ] | Kristen Goans | 779 Wilbud Drive | Cincinnati, OH 45205 | (513) 926-1908
Live | | example3@gmail.com | example3 | Order Date: Mar 19, 2015 | Delivered | 7 Orders | 2 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-4404 ] | VISA [ XXXX-5584 ] | Sara White | 904 Cypress Pkwy | Kissimmee, FL 34759 | (407) 870-1903
```

after :

```
Live | | example1@gmail.com | example1 | Order Date: May 1, 2015 | 5 Orders | 1 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-4374 ] | Alba Fitzpatrick | 26994 Brickville Rd | Sycamore, IL 60178 | (815) 508-0315
Live | | example2@gmail.com | example2 | Order Date: May 1, 2015 | Picked up | 24 Orders | 5 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-7814 ] | VISA [ XXXX-0370 ] | VISA [ XXXX-2441 ] | VISA [ XXXX-8129 ] | VISA [ XXXX-9986 ] | Kristen Goans | 779 Wilbud Drive | Cincinnati, OH 45205 | (513) 926-1908
Live | | example3@gmail.com | example3 | Order Date: Mar 19, 2015 | Delivered | 7 Orders | 2 Cards | VISA [ XXXX-4404 ] | VISA [ XXXX-5584 ] | Sara White | 904 Cypress Pkwy | Kissimmee, FL 34759 | (407) 870-1903
```

What regex code to delete all list die?

Comment: Please post what you have attempted so far and what results you see from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for   -  `^Die.*$\r?\n`
Replace with - `(Nothing)`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lE7iE0/1)